# Not supporting Offscreencanvas in angular version 17

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

Not supporting Offscreencanvas in angular version 17

**Error: error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'offscreencanvas'.                                                  The file is in the program because:                                                     Entry point of type library 'offscreencanvas' specified in compilerOptions**

After upgrading to Angular 17, the SCSS styling for mat-table is not being applied. I'm seeking guidance on how to implement mat-table functionality within Angular 17.